# Помогите с телеграмм ботом

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Выдаёт такую ошибку при открытии телеграмм ботп на python что делать?

```
File "C:\Users\GAGIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 498, in send raise ConnectionError(err, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))
```

Вот сам код:

```
import telebot;

bot = telebot.TeleBot('MyToken');
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "Привет":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет, чем я могу тебе помочь?")
    elif message.text == "/help":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Напиши привет")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Я тебя не понимаю. Напиши /help.")
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: Зачем вы обернули ошибку и код в JavaScript фрагменты? Используйте простое форматирование (4 пробела спереди, или ```)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте прокси, если запускаете бота с русского сервера. Возможно дело в этом

```
from telebot import apihelper
apihelper.proxy = { ' http ' : ' http://x.x.x.x:x ' }
```

Но если хотите использовать Socket5 то нужно установить зависимость:

> pip install requests[socks]

И желательно чтобы у вас стояла последняя версия библиотек: `gunicorn`, `PySocks`, `pyTelegramBotAPI`, `requests` и `urllib3`.

И команда будет выглядеть так:

```
apihelper.proxy = { ' https ' : ' socks5: // userproxy: пароль @ proxy_address: порт ' }
```